# What is the purity of $\rho_A$ for separable sates $\rho$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, density-operator

Consider the separable state, symbols having their usual meaning:

$$\rho_{AB} = \sum\limits_{i} p_{i}\, \rho^{i}_{A}\otimes\rho^{i}_{B} \quad .$$

We can obtain $\rho_{A}$ by tracing over system B, since $\mathrm{Tr}[\rho_{B}] = 1$, we obtain:

$$\rho_{A} = \sum\limits_{i} p_{i} \,\rho^{i}_{A} \quad ,$$ now, obtaining purity as:

$$\mathrm{Tr}[\rho^2_{A}] = \sum\limits_{i}p^2_{i} + 2\sum_{i,j}p_{i}p_{j}\,\mathrm{Tr}[\rho^{i}_{A}\rho^{j}_{A}] \quad .$$

We know that a separable state has no entanglement, thus purity must be 1 here, for that $\mathrm{Tr}[\rho^{i}_{A}\rho^{j}_{A}]$ must be 1. How do I show that? It seems true, if I diagonalize both $\rho^{i,j}$ but what if they are both simultaneously diagonalizable?

Comment: Why do you think $\rho_A$ should be pure at all? Take $\rho=\rho_1 \otimes \rho_2$ with $\rho_1$ mixed. Then $\rho$ is separable but has a mixed density matrix. Put differently, for a separable state as you've given, even with $\rho_A^i$ pure, the reduced density matrix $\rho_A$ is a mixture of (pure) density matrices unless all $\rho_A^i$ are the same, $\rho_A=\rho_A^i$ for all $i$, and or $p_i\neq 0$ only for one $i$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your argument is that the purity of a subsystem's state is only a measure of entanglement *when the overall system is in a pure state*. This is because if the total system $A\cup B$ was in a non-entangled pure state $\vert \psi_A\rangle \otimes\vert \psi_B\rangle$, you would have pure states $\vert \psi_A\rangle$ and $\vert \psi_B\rangle$ for $A$ and $B$, respectively. On the other hand, you can show that, *if $A\cup B$ is in a pure state $\vert \psi \rangle$*, any subsystem state could only be mixed if $\vert\psi\rangle$ was not entangled.

But, if the whole system was in a mixed state, the purity of $A$ and $B$ don't necessarily reflect on the entanglement content. E.g., if we had a fully uncorrelated (mixed) state $\rho = \rho_A \otimes \rho_B$, you would have (in general) proper mixed states for $A$ and $B$, even though $\rho$ is definitely not entangled.